# Generate Avro schema file using POJO with default null in Java

Tags: java, jackson, avro

I'm trying to generate an Avro schema file with POJOs using this [reference](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/master/avro).

With this code I'm able to generate a file but I don't know how to add a `"default" : null` attribute in each object field.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new AvroFactory());
AvroSchemaGenerator gen = new AvroSchemaGenerator();
mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(SampleObject.class, gen);
AvroSchema schemaWrapper = gen.getGeneratedSchema();

org.apache.avro.Schema avroSchema = schemaWrapper.getAvroSchema();
String asJson = avroSchema.toString(true);
// ... (omitted) save string to .avsc file
```

For a POJO field, what I generated is this:

```
...
{
  "name" : "fieldName",
  "type" : [ "null", "string" ]
},...
```

But what I want to generate for all fields is something like this:

```
...
{
  "name" : "fieldName",
  "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
  "default" : null
},...
```

How can I add `"default" : null` in all the generated fields when generating the schema using a POJO? What I have are the POJO classes and I want to convert them into Avro schema files.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just define the type and default value as an union. Like this:

```
{
  "name" : "fieldName",
  { "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }
}
```